# How do I retrieve the most recent record for each user in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access table with the following data:

```
MatchID - UserID - Result
```

The Match table contains a Date/Time stamp for every Match.

How can I build a query that shows the most recent date and result for each User in the database?

Here's my current code, which throws an error:

> Your query does not include the specified expression 'PlayerName' as part of an aggregate function.

```
SELECT Max(tblMatch.[MatchStart]) AS [MostRecent], tblPlayer.PlayerName
FROM (tblMatch
INNER JOIN tblParticipant ON tblMatch.MatchID=tblParticipant.ParticipantID)
INNER JOIN tblPlayer ON tblParticipant.ParticipantID=tblPlayer.PlayerID
GROUP BY tblParticipant.ParticipantID;
```

Comment: That got me somewhere, but added a new error I wasn't expecting.

Comment: Query you posted does not follow example. Use Access query designer. Build inner aggregate query object. Build outer query referencing saved object. Can then copy/paste SQL of first query into second to produce all-in-one statement then delete the first one.